# Python Loop over Key Value Pair

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, arraylist, key-value

I have an input file list called INPUTLIST.txt that currently looks like this:

```
KV:123
LDAP:456
AWS:789
PKI:222
```

In all honesty though, I'm not entirely fussed about its presentation, but there's plenty of flexibility for the above list to be saved in any suitable format, including these two below:

```
{'KV':123, 'LDAP':456, 'AWS':789, 'PKI':222}

['KV':123, 'LDAP':456, 'AWS':789, 'PKI':222]
```

Using Python, my main requirement though is to iterate through this input list using perhaps a For loop to retrieve each Key and Value pair, so I can go on to execute some additional commands. For example, I'll have something like this:

```
  for b in $(cat INPUTLIST.txt)
    do

      echo $b[0] // The key, e.g. KV/LDAP
      echo $b[1] // The corresponding value, e.g. 123/456
      python3 main_script.py $b[0] $b[1]  // Execute a Python script and pass the two values as arguments.
    
  done
```

Following the reading of each key-value pair, the main requirement is to now be able to execute another script (in this case a Python script I'm calling `main_script.py` and pass the key-value pair as arguments, as depicted above.

Any ideas or recommendation on what would be an ideal solution?

Comment: So, do it in Python, not in bash.  It's easy to read and split lines.  You can call other scripts from Python using `subprocess`.

Comment: is there a reason why you wouldn't to everything within python? have the script opening and parsing the file?

Comment: If you do it in python you could just read in the files line by line with `.readlines()` that returns a `list[str]` of lines. Then remove `\n` if necessary, split by `:`, and you have a list of `[key, value]` for each line. Then use `subprocess` to launch the scripts with the key/value pair.

Comment: Thanks for the various comments, especially the queries on why I'm not running everything strictly in Python. There's a little caveat to that and that's because I'm actually running all this in a GitLab pipeline (.gitlab-ci.yml), hence the combined use of bash, python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your file in this format - {'KV':123, 'LDAP':456, 'AWS':789, 'PKI':222} you can iterate through it as below

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for key, value in data.items():
    print(f'key: {key}-- value: {value}')
```